# Remove Duplicates From Table With The Same DisplayID

Tags: mysql, duplicates, heidisql

I have a table which is as follows:

```
Name   DisplayID InventoryType Itemlevel RequiredLevel  
Armor1      4           4         566      90
Armor2      123         30        566      90
Armor3      123         30        540      90
Armor4      123         10        540      90
```

What I want to do is, delete The DisplayId Duplicates From Each InventoryType and leaving the one with the Highest Itemlevel.

HeidiSQL, MySQL

Comment: Which RDBMS you use - MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle, ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.name, a.DisplayID, a.InventoryType, a.Itemlevel, a.RequiredLevel
FROM Item_template a
WHERE a.Itemlevel = (SELECT MAX(b.Itemlevel) FROM Item_template b where a.DisplayID = b.DisplayID)
```

SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bba95/1/0

Comment: Hi, thank you, but i'm to much of a novice to understand this one, i pasted it in the query, but it gave errors.  The Table name is Item_template and i'm using Heidisql, dont know if that would help

Comment: @QuincentMaduro updated code with table name try now

Comment: Thank you Matt! Still a few duplicates left, but removed 90% of them, Over 5k rows, so im happy!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using MS SQL as database server, you could do the following. I don't know if this is the most efficient way, but you get the result you're expecting I think.

```
declare @armorTable table (
    name nvarchar(10),
    displayId int,
    inventoryType int,
    itemLevel int,
    requiredLevel int
)

insert into @armorTable values ('Armor1',4,4,566,90)
insert into @armorTable values ('Armor2',123,30,566,90)
insert into @armorTable values ('Armor3',123,30,540,90)
insert into @armorTable values ('Armor4',123,10,540,90)

select
    *
from
(
    select
        *,
        (RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY displayId, inventoryType ORDER BY displayId, inventoryType, itemLevel)) Ranking
    from
        @armorTable 
) subQuery
where
    Ranking = 1
```

So, what this does is RANKING your armor table. It partitions (groups it) by 'displayId' and 'inventoryType', and then ranks the results in the order it finds. Because I ordered it on 'itemLevel', you give the highest itemLevel RANK 1, and the next RANK 2, etc.

This gives the following result:

```
name    displayId   inventoryType   itemLevel   requiredLevel   Ranking
Armor1  4           4               566         90              1
Armor4  123         10              540         90              1
Armor3  123         30              540         90              1
Armor2  123         30              566         90              2
```

Now, you want to remove all 'Ranking' values with another value than 1. Because you can't use RANK() directly in the where clause you have to use a subquery to do this.

When you do this you get the following result:

```
name    displayId   inventoryType   itemLevel   requiredLevel   Ranking
Armor1  4           4               566         90              1
Armor4  123         10              540         90              1
Armor3  123         30              540         90              1
```

You can find more about RANK() on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx)

Comment: Hi, The column i gave was just an example, i have over 20k rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try following to delete duplicate records per your criteria, but note that if you have duplication in highest Itemlevel, you'll see all of them in the output:

```
DELETE Table1
  FROM Table1
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT DisplayID, InventoryType, MAX(Itemlevel) AS MaxItem
                  FROM Table1
                 GROUP BY DisplayID, InventoryType) AS Table2
     ON Table1.InventoryType = Table2.InventoryType
    AND Table1.DisplayID = Table2.DisplayID
    AND Table1.Itemlevel = Table2.MaxItem
 WHERE Table2.MaxItem IS NULL
```

Comment: Hi, it deleted 90% of the table! not sure why though. and there are still some duplicate DisplayIDs